Are certain elements not legal inside of a paragraph?
I have this short html document:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>

    <form method="post">
    </form>

    </p>

</body>
</html>

When I view the page source in Firefox, the closing </p> tag is highlighted in red, with this error tooltip text:

No "p" element in scope but a "p" end tag seen.

Why does Firefox say the element is invalid?  Why is the beginning <p> tag not in scope?

MDN web docs:

Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing </p> tag. See "Tag omission" below.


The start tag is required. The end tag may be omitted if the <p> element is immediately followed by an ..., <form>, ... element.

